# IE7/8 and the Goldilocks Approach (responsive webdesign) aren't working together

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, responsive-design, goldilocks-approach

... to be more precise: the browsers don't work with the Goldilocks I tweaked a little ... :/

The Goldilocks Approach > [goldilocksapproach.com](http://goldilocksapproach.com/)

My site (in progress) > [amordetango.nl/txp/test](http://www.amordetango.nl/txp/test)

It has to be a minor thing but I'm glossing over it ...

Answer (score 0):

It's only because media queries are not supported by IE <= 8

Comment: **Boris** ... Goldilocks does the responsive thing with em's (for a good reason) and indeed IE7/8 doesn't support media queries. You can use respond.js but that script only works if the media queries are pixel-based. Nevertheless IE7/8 should render the desktop layout ... and now they do (well ... allmost) because now I included the correct path to the proper .css file ... :%